# Android studio throws a duplicate class error when annotationProcessor is added

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I recently just started with android development using kotlin so a total noob at android studio too.
I am trying to build a super simple HelloWorld app but I got this error:

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>     - jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar)
>   Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>   See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

but when I added the annotationprocessor at the end of my dependencies like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    annotationProcessor "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"

}
```

I encountered a new error instead when I tried to build:

https://del.dog/pyfunestin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class duplicate error can be solved by cleaning the project. First clean the project and rebuild it.